# deleting x.509 v3 extensions from issued certificate

Tags: x509

I need to make light weight PKC for that i want to delete x509 v3 extensions from the user certificate. May i use this openssl command to delete v3 extensions?

openssl x509 -in /usr/local/openca/var/openca/crypto/certs/E841B2655206FA6A3ADA.pem -noout -text -certopt no_extensions -out /usr/local/openca/var/openca/crypto/certs/ -out 
E841B2655206FA6A3ADA_nov3ext.pem

or where should i make changes to generate x509 v1 certificate since it doesn't contain x509 extensions. could you please provide me a link for the reference.

thanks for your time.

Comment: You are aware that the extensions are a signed part of the certificate, aren't you? Thus, by deleting them, the certificate chain of your certificate won't verify anymore. Furthermore, even with extensions removed your certificates may have to be at least version v2 if unique identifiers are present.

Answer (score 2):

Usually (well, virtually *always* really!) the signature does not just cover the distinguished name on the cert; but everything else as well (serial, expiry dates, etc).

So while it is not hard to cut down the certificate to size - it will instantly invalidate the signature by its issuer.

However - in some cases it is possible to do something else - and that is dispense/ignore the signature part of the cert completely; and just focus on the public key.

Use someting like

```
cat somecert.pem | openssl x509 -pubkey -nout
```

to get just the public key. So forego all of X509 and in essense no longer have a PKI. Just pairs of raw public keys and private keys.

Then in your application commit the fairly unforgivable gaffe of inventing your own crypto - and have the owner of that public key sign something like a NONCE with its private key; and validate the signature. E.g.

```
# the 'server' sends a nonce to the client
openssl rand -base64 128 > send-to-client
```

then on the client it is signed

cat msg-from-server | openssl pkeyutl -inkey privkey.pem -sign | base64 > send-to-server

and on the server we check this

```
cat msg-from-client | openssl pkeyutl -in pubkey-of-client.pem -verify
```

and take things form there. However unless you are a kick-ass cryptographer and protocol designer, schemes like this (and above certainly does!) are riddled with flaws and pitfalls.

But in theory it does let you use just a few 1000 bytes of RSA keys; or a few 100 bytes of Elliptic curve based keys.